# How to reuse the `apt up` part of the `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands to execute both in sequence in just one line

Tags: bash, terminal

For learning purposes, I want to know if its possible and if it is, how to reuse the `apt up` part of the `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands to execute both in sequence in just one line? i.e.: `sudo apt up{date|grade}`

Comment: It's not possible, not in any easy way I can think of. You have to type out both commands.

Comment: what about something like `alias up='sudo bash -c "apt update && apt upgrade" '`?

Comment: We can't create an alias for every time we run this command.

Everything must be done in just one line, no external help files or aliased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print commands on two lines and pipe to xargs:

```
printf "apt up%s\n" date grade | xargs -l sudo
printf "up%s\n" date grade | xargs -l sudo apt
printf "%s\n" date grade | xargs -i sudo apt up{}
```

Similar with [evil `eval`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048):

```
eval $(printf "sudo apt up%s\n" date grade)
```

Similar design, but more bash expansions:

```
eval $(printf %s\; "sudo apt up"{date,grade})
sudo sh -c "$(printf %s\; apt\ up{date,grade})"
```

Another one, knowing that `xargs` splits on spaces:

```
echo up{date,grade} | xargs -n1 sudo apt
```

But really, just a loop:

```
for i in date grade; do sudo apt up$i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `eval` (a bash built-in) you can try this:

```sh
eval "sudo apt up"{"date &&",grade}
```

This will run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` for you. The first term in `{}` is quoted because it has space and `&`. If you want to add `-y` option to `upgrade` you should use like this:

```sh
eval "sudo apt up"{"date &&","grade -y"}
```

Note that `eval` can be dangerous so check again before issuing the command.

Comment: For generality for future viewers, I'd like to suggest you changing the title to something like "suppress common parts from multiple commands in bash"